# EBootstrapActiveForm shows "(Required)" instead of *

Tags: php, yii

When I use

```
    <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('EBootstrapActiveForm', array(...
```

instead of

```
    <?php $form=$this->beginWidget('CActiveForm', array(...,
```

the default required fields mark `*` is replaced with the word "(Required)". How can I get back the * mark? Following is the input field snippet I am using:

```
    <?php echo $form->beginControlGroup($model, 'first_name'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->labelEx($model,'first_name'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->beginControls(); ?>
        <?php echo $form->textField($model,'first_name',array('size'=>60,'maxlength'=>64)); ?>
        <?php echo $form->error($model,'first_name'); ?>
    <?php echo $form->endControls(); ?>
    <?php echo $form->endControlGroup(); ?>
```

Comment: what are the params after 'EBootstrapActiveForm', array(...?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based [source code](https://github.com/VisualAppeal/YiiBootstrap/blob/master/EBootstrap.php#L494) of the extension required label mark can be changed this way:

```
EBootstrap::$afterRequiredLabel = '*';
```

Place it anywhere before calling `EBootstrapActiveForm` widget.

Answer (score 0):

Based on EBootstrapActiveForm, the default mark should not be changed!

[Full example at their website](http://visualappeal.github.com/YiiBootstrap/index.php/site/contact/index.html) shows `*` marks.